# Как реализовать постоянное нахождение в личном кабинете android-приложения?

Tags: android

Пишу android-приложение. Каждый раз при входе в него необходимо вбивать логин и пароль. Как сделать так, чтобы при входе однажды нахождение в личном кабинете было постоянным, пока пользователь сам не захочет выйти(как у приложения ВКонтакте)? Нужно ли для этого использовать Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Храни логин и пароль в SharedPreferences в если там что-то есть - логинься. Сервисы для этого совсем не нужны. По кнопке "разлогиниться" просто очищай данные.

Comment: неплохо еще сказать о том, что преференсы - простой текстовый файл и логин с паролем будет никак не защищен. то есть стрит позаботииься о шифровании или использовать специальные инструменты андроид для хранения конфидициальных данных